# Sencha Architect Chart Themes - unrecognized Alias

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-architect

I want to define a custom theme for charts in my application per [Ext.chart.theme.Base](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.chart.theme.Base.html) But I'm not sure exactly where or how to define it properly to work in Architect design view. I've tried both as a resource and in Application.launch(). ***Both methods work for the app in Chrome/IE but not in design view.*** I've tried all manner of requires 'Ext.chart.theme.*', 'chart.theme.mycharttheme', 'chart.theme.MyChartTheme' and design view seems to refuse to recognize the alias.

Any ideas? Whats the proper way to define a chart theme that is architect compatible?

In Architect design view I get the error below

> [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: chart.theme.mycharttheme

chart/theme/MyChartTheme.js

```js
Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.myChartTheme', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
    singleton: true,
    alias: [
        'chart.theme.mycharttheme'
    ],
    config: {
        colors : [ '#5DD2E0','#5ABCCF','#58A7BC','#5492A9',
                  '#4F7E95','#496A81','#42576D','#394659' ]    
    }
});
```

extjs Version : 6.5.1
Architect version : 4.2.2

Comment: And do you have `chart/theme/MyChartTheme.js` created in the SA interface or you did it outside of SA?

Comment: Its in the resources section in the SA interface with a url of chart/theme/myChartTheme.js

Comment: Yeah I think SA is not able to load these config files to the canvas (design view)